# how to download JSON file using Python from a URL with authentication key

Tags: python, json, api, authentication, download

I am trying to download JSON files from a website that is being accessed with username and password (API service), but without success.

I am using Python3.

Using the one below, I get an 'invalid syntax' error:

```
NG_AT = urllib.request.urlretrieve(('https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/AT?limit=7', auth=(username, api_token)), 'AT.json')
```

I need to be able to download the `.json` file that exists in the above link directly to a file called 'AT.json'.

Comment: please post the whole error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use **requests** lib in python

install it with:

```
pip install requests
```

and run this code:

```
import requests
headers = {
    "Host": "agsi.gie.eu",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
}
resp = requests.get("https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/AT?limit=7", headers=headers)
with open("AT.json", "w") as my_file:
    my_file.write(resp.text)
```

Comment: thank you, the last part was what i needed:
'''
with open("AT.json", "w") as my_file:
    my_file.write(resp.text)
'''

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get a response with content using the API Key.

```
from requests import request
headers = {"x-key": "your_apikey_goes_here"}
r = request(method="GET",url="https://agsi.gie.eu/api/data/AT?limit=7", headers=headers)
```

Comment: thank you, i have tried this method alredy but could not move on from the Response to sth more in Python  such as dictionary or list. but the second answer to my problem provided the solution.